# Find the set of all vectors in R3 that are orthogonal to (-1,0,2) and (3,1,-2). Write the set in the standard form of a plane through the origin

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v = (-1,0,2)$ and $u = (3,1,-2)$ so we need to find $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that $v \cdot x = 0$ and $u \cdot x = 0$. This gives us the set of linear equations

$$ -x_1+2x_3 = 0$$ 
$$ 3x_1 + x_2 - 2x_3 = 0$$

which, through elementary row operations gets us the two linear equations
$$ x_1-2x_3 = 0$$ $$x_2 + 4x_3 = 0 $$

so $x_1 -2x_3 = x_2 + 4x_3$ which simplifies to $x_1 = x_2 + 6x_3$. so the solution set would be

{$(x_2+6x_3, x_2, x_3)$ | $x_3,x_2\in \mathbb R$}

But the answer is {$r(2,-1,4)$ | $r \in R$}. How do i get this/did I make an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was to assume that $x_2$ and $x_3$ are indepedent, what is not true, since you have got the equation $x_2+4x_3=0$. To get the right result, just chose one variable to be parametrized and using both equations you got, find the relation of the other two variables to this parameter.

Comment: So $s = (1,0,-2) - (0,1,4) = (1, -1, -6)$?

Comment: Didn't understand the comment. Make the following: set $x_3=r$. From the equations you got, you get that $x_1=2r$ and $x_2=-4r$. So the vectors you are looking for are $\{r(2,-4,1)|r \in \mathbb{R}\}$. You can see that this answer is the right one by making the inner product with the vectors $u$ and $v$, while the one you posted is not.

Comment: I feel so silly. Thanks, Mateus. You're my best friend